# What is the current view of which emotions exist?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, psychology

I had previously drawn a map of which emotions exists based on this paper: https://www.pnas.org/content/114/38/E7900.

But now that I opened my college textbook 'understanding motivation and emotion' by Johnmarshall Reeve I find that he uses another set of emotions such as anger and contempt (basic emotions) that isn't a part of the above mentioned paper's model. I find in the book's references that his writing is based on papers older than the one I have linked, but the book is of an edition written more recently than the paper. He mentions that he has spent his entire life in the field of emotion and motivation, so are the ones in the paper i linked still debated?

What is the current view on which emotions to exist, as an industry standard and/or are the most accurate, and that I should model my view of human emotions to fit?

Vincent-Emil